# Could someone make me understand the algorithm running behind this in the most detailed way possible?

Tags: python, oop, decorator

I know `dec1()` is a `decorator` and decorates `who_is_nimo()` function. There are several things at which I'm confused.

1. Can't we decorate the function without creating `nowexec()` function inside `dec1(func1)`? I tried doing like this and it exactly give the same output like before(different from the main code).

```
def dec1(func1):
    print("Executing Now!")
    func1()
    print("Executed!")

@dec1
def who_is_nimo():
    print("Nimo")


who_is_nimo
```

2. If we run `who_is_nimo`(without parenthesis) and return `nowexec()`(With parenthesis), then also the output is same. What exactly is going here?

Main Code:

```
def dec1(func1):
    def nowexec():
        print("Executing Now!")
        func1()
        print("Executed!")
    return nowexec

@dec1
def who_is_nimo():
    print("Nimo")


who_is_nimo()
```

Comment: Did you *try* the first code? Because it doesn't work

Comment: "If we run who_is_nimo(without parenthesis) and return nowexec()(With parenthesis), then also the output is same. What exactly is going here?" No, if you do that, *it raises an error*

Comment: A decorator is required to return a function.

Comment: You should try both examples with: `who_is_nimo(); who_is_nimo()` at the end.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oops I forgot to remove those paranthesis from who_is_nimo at the end. Try now, I have edited this.

Comment: When you have just `who_is_nimo` at the end, it does nothing. You can remove it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It doesn't raise an error. I have already tried doing it and it works fine.

Comment: @quamrana What exactly is the difference between two?

Comment: @VarghabShib prior to your edit *it absolutely did*

Comment: @VarghabShib `some_func` just references the function. `some_func()` **calls the functon**

Comment: Did you ``print(who_is_nimo)`` in both cases? In how far does the information available to you not explain things sufficiently? Explaining something "in the most detailed way possible" is going to be a *long* writeup.

Comment: If you have: `who_is_nimo(); who_is_nimo()` for the second snippet, you see `Nimo` printed twice. If you have `who_is_nimo; who_is_nimo` at the end of the first snippet, you see `Nimo` just once.

Comment: Basically, (1) is completely wrong. `dec1` returns `None`, so now, `who_is_nimo` is `None`, and if you ever try to use it like the function, e.g. `who_is_nimo()` it will raise a `TypeError`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It would be great if you refer me to some link.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, why exactly it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Decorator syntax is syntactic sugar for function application; basically,

```
@dec1
def who_is_nimo():
    print("Nimo")
```

is equivalent to

```
def who_is_nimo():
    print("Nimo")


who_is_nimo = dec1(who_is_nimo)
```

So what is the return value of `dec1`?

In your first case, it's whatever its argument returns when called. That is, ignoring the output produced by `print`,

```
who_is_nimo = who_is_nimo()
```

In your second case, `dec1` creates a *new* function each time it is called, and that function keeps a reference to (i.e., closes over) the argument to `dec1`. As a result, `who_is_nimo` is bound to a new function that, when called, calls the *original* function that was bound to `who_is_nimo`. With a little bit of renaming, it has the same effect as

```
def who_is_nimo():
    print("Nimo")

tmp = who_is_limo  # Second reference to function currently bound to who_is_nimo

def nowexec():
    print("Executing Now!")
    tmp()
    print("Executed!")

who_is_nimo = now_exec
```

The main difference is that here, `tmp` is a global variable that can easily be changed, affecting how `now_exec` behaves. With the decorator, `func1` is a ncn-local variable that is *part of* the definition of `now_exec`, and cannot be (easily) changed.

Comment: In my second snippet, you can see I have not executed the function ```nowexec``` while returning as I have not called it with parenthesis, then why the content inside of ```nowexec()``` gets executed when I called ```who_is_nimo()``` function?

Comment: Because the name `who_is_nimo` now *refers* to that function; you returned it from the decorator. When you write `who_is_nimo()`, you are calling that function, *not* the original function bound to `who_is_nimo`. That function is only only accessible from the name `func1` inside the current value of `who_is_nimo`.